# How to troubleshoot apparent slowdown of a .NET process hosted in IIS?

Tags: .net, performance, iis

Our application server hosting WCF services is hosted by IIS running on Windows Server 2008R2. There are many application pools running on the box. It is a very large 8-core server, containing 64GB of RAM.
Over time, we see the performance of the web service degrade, for no obvious reason. The requests run to completion, but they run far slower than normal. We have found no other impediments in the environment. The database is fine and responsive. There is plenty of free memory on the server and there is plenty of available CPU.

The only clues we have are:

1. The problem starts to occur when the memory consumption of the application pool grows beyond 3.5GB.
2. Recycling the application pool clears the problem immediately (but is not desirable owing to startup costs).
3. The applications runtime behavior is not friendly, in that there is a lot of transient data held long enough to make it into generation 2 before finally being discarded. So there are an excessive number of promotions to gen 2. There are also large object heap allocations (also transient) for outbound data.

Our first hypothesis of course was that the process is spending too much time in garbage collection (gen 2 specifically), but this is not evident from the %time in GC performance counter, or the number of gen 2 GCs. Also, once the application pool enters this slow-performing state, it remains there until the pool is recycled. Even if the pool is idle for some time, or only one request is sent to it, it’s slow. That implies that somehow the pool heaps are now in a state that all garbage collections are expensive. Our thinking is that once GC has taken place, performance should be normal again. Or is this wrong?

My question is what can cause this behaviour? How can we troubleshoot it? Is there any meaningful statistics that we can collect to help us understand the problem?

The runtime is .Net 4.5.0, the compilation target is 4.0.

Comment: Do you mind giving the reasons for why this question should be closed?

Comment: Only a comment and reach but if you are running on Standard try Enterprise.

Comment: It is Enterprise. I do not think one can have 64GB of RAM on the Standard.

Comment: I think you can have it but not use it.  I said a reach.  I would look at tuning the Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency of the WCF.

Comment: You said that the problem starts to occur when memory reaches 3.5GB. My question is how much memory is your process using? What was its maximum usage? The memory grows all the time or achieves some stable level?

Comment: The application working set has risen to 3.5GB and higher, but the actual data on the heap is small (between requests). It’s a web service server that often will produce very large responses (possibly involving the large object heap depending on size). However, between these requests the memory does not grow significantly. We’ve cached probably 20-30 MB that’s made it to generation 2 on the heap. I would say we trigger garbage collection excessively, but we don’t leak memory or grow at a bad rate.

Answer (score 0):

ETW tracing is normal a good way to diagnose such perf problem: try download PerfView from Microsoft. If not CPU, memory, then check thread, especially synchronization issues. There are tons of ETW providers you can turn on to diagnose perf issues.